# Loading JQuery with Javascript from footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

**If you would like to get to the point, here is my question:** 
Is there any way to call a specific script to load first in javascript?

**For more detail, please read below:**

I have a javascript file that is loading from the bottom of my HTML `<body>`. Unfortunately, there is no JQuery in the head, so I have to add it through this javascript file.

What I need to do is add a JQuery lightbox plugin.

My problem is that when I load the page, sometimes JQuery isn't the first thing loaded. So I receive the error "jQuery is not defined". Which will then raise more errors for undefined methods from the plugin.

This doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes. Which makes me think it's a loading/order of operations issue.

Is there any way I can guarantee that my JQuery script is the first thing loaded?

Here is some of my javascript file.

```
//Get head element
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

//Create and insert JQuery
var jquery = document.createElement('script');
jquery.type = 'text/javascript';
jquery.src = 'http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe6b/m/1/jquery.1.7.2.js';

head.insertBefore(jquery,head.childNodes[4]);

function thescripts() { 

    var fancybox = document.createElement('script');
    fancybox.type = 'text/javascript';
    fancybox.src = 'http://image.iloqal.com/ilejquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js';
    head.appendChild(fancybox);

    var thebody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    thebody.appendChild(thediv);
    thediv.appendChild(theimg);


    //Run fancybox
    thebody.onload = function() {

    $('#lightbox').ready(function() {
        $("#lightbox").fancybox().trigger('click');
    });
}
};
 if(jquery.attachEvent){
     jquery.attachEvent("onload",thescripts());
} else {
     jquery.onload = thescripts();  
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(function() {...do your stuff here...});` is the way to go to be sure jQuery is loaded before the script is executed, but you could probably make it harder for yourself and do:

```
thebody.onload = function() {
   RunMyjQuery();
}

function RunMyjQuery() {
    if (typeof $ === 'undefined') {
         setTimeout(RunMyjQuery, 500);
    }else{
        $('#lightbox').ready(function() {
            $("#lightbox").fancybox().trigger('click');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: RECURSION! Why didn't I think of that?! I'm no longer getting the error thank you! Although, this does raise a new error for me that I'm unfamiliar with. '"create" can only be used in extension processes.', is this an issue with onload and attaching events?

Comment: Should'nt be, but it's hard to tell what the problem is exactly, but if it's createElement, that should work just fine in onload handlers. Also there should be some sort of timeout on the whole thing, so if jQuery for some reason does not load at all, the interval does'nt keep on going forever, on the other hand, if jQuery is needed for the site to display correctly, it does'nt really matter!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Add this piece of code inside your javascript file which is called from your footer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></'+'script>');
  }

</script>
```

This will include jquery if its not loaded. I think this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this before and it doesn't necessarily fix it, but it definitely has a faster load time, allowing jquery to load first. I'll be sure to keep this implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `thescripts` immediately, although you try not to. Use this:

```
jquery.onload = thescripts; // notice no parentheses
```

Also, your `thebody.onload` strategy will not work. Use `$(document).ready` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('#lightbox').ready(function() {
        $("#lightbox").fancybox().trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this now, I'll need to reorganize some of the script. Thanks!